# How can I extend a generic type in TypeScript without needing to redeclare all the generic type parameters from the base type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My use case is that I am developing a library which has many types which share common generic properties. I want all of these types to be able to reuse a set of generic base properties without needing to redeclare them every time.

Here is some example code:

```js
// Declaring the base type
type BaseType<Name extends string> = {
    name: Name
}

// Extending the base type
type ExtendedType<Name extends string /* Redundant parameter */, Category extends string> = BaseType<Name> & {
    category: Category
}

// Using the extended type
const test: ExtendedType<'Microsoft', 'Software'> = {
    name: 'Microsoft',
    category: 'Software'
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBEFMGMBsEMBOBLAdgc1AFwBaVAEbwDO+WAngA6QBQF1oAQiZACpWQA8AcvALb5IADyyRUAE2KhiWFBgB8oALygA3jVCbQqfpABcoXgJoBfGjRCgAoiLHi0mXPiKlsHOh2u2Jkce2o8uqDCohJSMnKYwABUoABKvgCuEvCoWKCUSLqiiKDRwAA0oADC8KLoAPaI5MHektKyDooqzKT+XEaQigBkahpa0GWQldUGpeVV5KbmlgCqxA7YeLWh4r5u1DTQFagy2JAyBjarvu2cAOQAssjQiBXEFQBmWOdF5wDKT1gA7kiQ580+lptLoDFcbncHs9Xv1NIMJqNQB8vr9EP9TEA)

As you can see, even though `ExtendedType` is only adding one additional property to `BaseType`, it has to redeclare the generic type parameter of `BaseType`. I want a way to extend `BaseType` such that consumers of `ExtendedType` can pass type arguments required by both `ExtendedType` and `BaseType` without needing to redeclare all the type parameters in both types. This is a simplified example but it gets really tedious doing this for more complex types with deep inheritance.

Comment: This is not currently possible as asked.  There's a feature request at [ms/TS#32044](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32044) for this, but it's not implemented.  Currently the version you're using is the recommended way.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer. If not, what am I missing?